# how to append array numpy with different length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i have simply code like this

```
for item in images:
  img_org = nii_reader(item)
  img = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(img_org)
  print(img.shape)
```

and the output like this

```
(9, 40, 43)
(9, 46, 50)
(8, 40, 38)
(6, 46, 45)
(4, 47, 44)
(8, 57, 54)
(7, 45, 44)
(8, 53, 49)
(8, 45, 48)
```

i want all img into an array. i have tried code like this

```
train = np.array([])
for item in images:
  img_org = nii_reader(item)
  img = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(img_org)
  train = np.append(train, img)
print(train.shape)
```

but the lenght is

```
(1728287,)
```

how can i append to get the lenght like this ?

```
(9, 9, 57, 54)
```

Comment: Start with a `np.zeros` array of the desired shape, and copy each image array to it.  The copy will require slices to place the smaller arrays properly into the larger block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably cannot do that with `np.stack`. Since it requires each array to have the same dimensions as stated in the [manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html).
In your case, it will require each of your `img` to have the same height, width and length. I think your best luck is to make your `train` a list and append your `img`s to it.

On top of my memory, appending objects to lists are actually faster than concatinating numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use np.stack to achieve this if you add your array "train" to the np.stack function with the axis=0 to stack all the images appended in the train array.

```
train = np.stack(train, axis=0)
print(train.shape)
```